# Send backspace key event to edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I don't know how to send a backspace key event to a `EditText` from my own button. Here is what i tried:

```
Button backSpace=(Button)findViewById(R.id.backSpace_tab);
backSpace.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        text.dispatchKeyEvent(new  KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_P));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the [Android developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KeyEvent%28int,%20int%29):

> public **KeyEvent** (int action, int code)
>
> Create a new key event.
>
> **Parameters**
>   *action*    Action code: either ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP, or ACTION_MULTIPLE.
>   *code*      The key code

The first parameter should be an action code. In your case you should use [ACTION_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN), because you want to simulate a keypress:

> public static final int **ACTION_DOWN**
>
> getAction() value: the key has been pressed down.

So this should work:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    text.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
}
```