# Clearing the single character before cursor position in EditText

Tags: android, button, cursor-position

With the below code i am replacing the all characters(if my edittext contains four a's all a's are removed here) that contains substring and the cursor position is goes to before first character in edittext field.

```
//getting cursor position 
int end = t1.getSelectionEnd();
//getting the selected Text
String selectedStr = t1.getText().toString().substring(end-1, end);
//replacing the selected text with empty String and setting it to EditText
t1.setText(t1.getText().toString().replace(selectedStr, ""));
```

How can i clear the single character before the cursor position(if my cursor is middle of the edittext) without changing the cursor position.

Comment: How about simulating a backspace event? like the trick in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145758/send-backspace-key-event-to-edit-text

Answer (score 5):

I think its late but still.

You can use SpannableStringBuilder.

```
//getting cursor position 
int end = t1.getSelectionEnd();
//getting the selected Text
SpannableStringBuilder selectedStr=new SpannableStringBuilder(t1.getText());
//replacing the selected text with empty String and setting it to EditText
selectedStr.replace(end-1, end, "");
edittext1.setText(selectedStr);
```

Comment: Also to keep cursor position this will be required edittext1.setSelection(end-1);

Answer (score 1):

I solved with this function:

```
int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
if (pos > 0)
    String text = editText.getText().delete(pos - 1, pos).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect solution try this...
Wherever you will put your cursor the value will gets remove from that position

```
  Editable editable = yourEditText.getText();
    int charCount = mDigits.getSelectionEnd();
    if (charCount > 0) {
    editable.delete(charCount - 1, charCount);
    }
```