# Continuously delete contents of EditText on button hold Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, backspace

How do I delete one by one the current text of edit text when I press a button and continuously delete the text one by one when I hold the press of button. Similar to what a backspace button does.

Sending a backspace event won't work on my needs because it will only work if the keyboard is active. Im not using any keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Timer for this.It continuously checks the button state pressed or not. Like:

```
private Timer _timer;

final Button _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
final EditText _editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
_timer = new Timer();
TimerTask _task = new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

 @Override
 public void run() {
    Editable _editable = _editText.getText();
    int length = _editable.length();
    _editText.setSelection(length);
    if (_button.isPressed() && length > 0) {
        _editable.delete(length - 1, length);
        }

    }
 });
}
};
_timer.schedule(_task, 0, 60);
```

Just cancel the Timer in onDestroy() method, Like:

```
_timer.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a BACKSPACEKEY EVENT to your EditText.

Here is the sample for what you want [Send backspace key event to edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145758/send-backspace-key-event-to-edit-text).

**Edit**

Manually you can do like this

- Get the String from `edittext`.
- Delete the char at last index. For this you can use method `subString` of `String` class.

Recursively do this process until your String becomes empty.

Comment: this only works when I have focus on the edit text and the keyboard is showing ... I am using this on a custom dial app .so I created my own buttons for the numbers so I am not using the keyboard of edit text