# clear the contents of the editText when long press on Back Space Key

Tags: java, android, text, backspace

Because my editext is the string format it doesn't clear all the text when i long press on the backspace key. so i am looking  for solution to clear all text when long press on the backspace key ??

Comment: Set your edit text to bind with listener and implement logic inside

Comment: could you give me sample code  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/20987540/2700586

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overriding `onKeyLongPress()` like

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
{ 
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    myTextView.setText("");
    return true; 
} 
return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
```

}

Comment: i override onKeyLongPress listenner on Activity but it doesn't call when i long press on the  backspace key??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) 
  { 
    textView.setText("");
    return true; 
  } 
return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
```

Comment: i override onKeyLongPress listenner on Activity but it doesn't call when i long press on the  backspace key??