# Clear all content of an EditText when backspace key is longpressed?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-view, textview

So I have an `EditText` with the `inputType` as `numberDecimal` (I don't think this matters but whatever)... I want it so that when I press and hold the backspace key (longpress) all the numbers in the `EditText` are deleted at once instead of rapidly one at a time as is the current behavior. Is this possible? The only thread I could find about this issue is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428633/clear-the-contents-of-the-edittext-when-long-press-on-back-space-key) but I tried implementing that solution (overriding `onKeyLongPress())` and that method never gets called.

Comment: Are you testing with device that has a physical back button? I have tested the `onKeyLongPress()` method on two devices--one with a physical back button and this works. The other device has a on screen back button and the `onKeyLongPress()` method is not being called.

Comment: @Barns testing on the emulator and my personal device (Pixel XL). Both don't have physical back buttons, they are on-screen back buttons. Does any modern Android device even have physical back buttons now-a-days?

Comment: Probably not! I have several devices and only one (with Marshmallow 6.0) has a physical back button. On the devices without a physical back button I get the `onKeyDown()` method to fire but not the `onKeyLongPress()`.  I saw one implementation where the "delete" button of the soft keys was used to observer the `onKeyLongPress()` and then delete all characters in the `EditText` view, which I believe is more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {  
            //this is for backspace
        }
        return false;       
    }
});
```